# Web Part JavaScript is not working for other users

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, form

I added a Web Part on new form page for a list, and added JavaScript code to it, which is working as expected for my SharePoint account. The same script is not working for any other user using the list that I created.

How to make the script to work for other users?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://site-name/Style%20Library/sputility.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{   
    var statusFld = SPUtility.GetSPField('Status');
    var status    = statusFld.GetValue();

    var node = document.querySelector('[title="Status"]');
    if(status  === "In Review") {
        if(node) {
           node.disabled = true;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please add code you used to your question? Have you added code directly or referenced code file from somewhere else? Is you have used to file reference then make sure other users have permission on that file.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Edited my question, added the script that I'm using.

Comment: Can you please check if the other user has permission on "Style Library" as well as "sputility.js"? Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Please check the browser dev console for any errors. It will help to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your code like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://site-name/Style%20Library/sputility.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {   
        var statusFld = SPUtility.GetSPField('Status');
        var status = statusFld.GetValue();

        var node = document.querySelector('[title^="Status"]'); //Using Starts with (^=) selector in JQuery benefits when your field is required.
        if(status === "In Review") {
            if(node) {
               node.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Note**:

1. Make sure that other users have permission on the references JavaScript files from **Style Library**.

Answer (score 0):

I just did "Check In" the `jquery.min.js` and `sputility.js` files. The problem was solved.